# Any two $A$-modules of the same dimension over $k$ isomorphic as $A$-modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a central simple $k$-algebra. Are any two $A$-modules of the same dimension over $k$ isomorphic as $A$-modules?

Comment: Why so many votes to close?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are.

$A$ is a simple Artinian ring. Therefore it has, up to isomorphism, a unique simple right $A$-module $S$ and every $A$-module is isomorphic to a direct sum $S^{(I)}$ for some index set $I$. Moreover, the module $S$ has some finite dimension $n$ over $k$. (Explicitly, $A$ is isomorphic to $M_r(D)$ for a division ring $D$ which is finite-dimensional over $k$. The simple module $S$ is then isomorphic to $D^r$ viewed as right $M_r(D)$-module in the natural way.)

Now suppose that $M$ and $N$ are two right $A$-modules with $\dim_k(M)=\dim_k(N)$. Then $M \cong S^{(I)}$ and $N \cong S^{(J)}$ for index sets $I$ and $J$. Since $\dim_k (M) = n |I|$ and $\dim_k(N) = n |J|$, it follows that $|I|=|J|$. Therefore $M \cong N$.

Comment: Why does there exist a unique simple $A-$module $S$, and why is every $A-$module isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $S$? Why does $S$ have finite dimension over $k$?